# The PyOptiX module is not found with the regular installation and the library is not found with the installation using wheel

Tags: python, pip, nvidia, optix

I'm trying to install PyOptiX (https://github.com/NVIDIA/otk-pyoptix). In order to do so, I've previously installed OptiX SDK 7.7 and set properly the environment variable as described in the installation instructions and I execute `python setup.py install` with no error or warning. However, when I try to execute the examples, `import optix` results in `ModuleNotFoundError`. `pip list` does not show the module either.

I've checked and the installation seems to be using easy-install. I found the reference to an .egg file in a easy-install.pth file which seems to be a deprecated way to install python packages.

I've created a wheel file using `python setup.py bdist_wheel` and then installed the wheel file using pip. After that, `pip list` shows optix, but `import optix` outputs `ImportError: Library not found`.

Any idea?

Edit: I'm working with Python 3.9 and all CUDA drivers are properly working.